# To avoid Qt Creator from source mistakes the version of Qt upon building

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I got the following error when I try building `Qt Creator` [from source](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.5.0-src.tar.gz).

```
user@host:/usr/share/qtcreator/qtcreator_build$ qmake -version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.2 in /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib
user@host:/usr/share/qtcreator/qtcreator_build$ sudo qmake ../qtcreator_fromSrc/qtcreator.pro 
Project MESSAGE: Cannot build Qt Creator with Qt version 4.6.2.
Project ERROR: Use at least Qt 4.7.4.
```

As shown, the `Qt` library in use above is 4.8.2, which should be qualifying ver 4.7.2. It's installed [from source](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-x11.html). How can I let the `qtcreator` installer recognize the right `qt` version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to copy the source of `Qt Creator` to the area that doesn't require super user permission. HTH.